# My yo generator showing errors while generating with yo command

Tags: angular, yo

I created a generator to scaffold my an angular2 application. I successfully able to put it in github, npm link, npm publish. I am also able to see my generator in yo generator list in yo site. When I try to install the generator, I am getting wired error

You don't seem to have a generator with the name my-generator-name installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you file and folder structures are as yo generator recommended. I have the same issue due to the missing of index.js file in my generators folder.

I would suggest install generator-generator and in compare you generator with that.

```
npm install -g generator-generator
yo generator
```

Comment: the index.js file in my generators folder was missing. fixed it now. Thanks